# Verify integrity of installed Ubuntu packages

Tags: security

I'm looking for a script that is run from a boot-CD doing the following for all files on a drive:

1. find the debian-package a file is from (if possible)
2. download and extract the debian-package
3. generate md5sums for the installed file and the downloaded file
4. list differences and files that weren't packaged

Is something like this readily available? (I don't trust the local deb-archive.)

Chris

Comment: 3 is done for you by the deb itself if I recall. I know #1 is possible with dpkg (too lazy to look it up right now, will post later)

Comment: The md5sums for #3 are stored locally and could be compromised. So that's no real solution.

Comment: For #4, do you mean [(list differences of files that were packaged) and (list files that weren't packaged)] or [(list differences of (files and those that were not packaged))]?

Comment: Also, if you are on a boot disc then dpkg/apt would not be using the local caches and so they could actually be used for fetching md5 sums. The live environment would have to download ***all*** of the packages on the system to the ramdrive however

Comment: Why not just `sudo apt-get install --reinstall $(sudo dpkg -l)` and go get some coffee?

Answer (score 2):

***Part 1***

```
sudo dpkg -S stdio.h
sudo dpkg -S stdio.h | cut -d ':' -f 1 > packages.list
```

source: [section 5.2](http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/apt-howto/ch-search.en.html)

***Part 2***

```
mkdir -p /tmp/archives/partial
apt-get -d -o dir::cache=/tmp -o Debug::NoLocking=1 install --reinstall  < packages.list
```

source: [Comment from dpk on Alfonso Vila's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4419268/how-do-i-download-a-package-from-apt-get-without-installing-it)

***Part 3***

Debs are Ar archives and can be manipulated with `ar`. MD5 hashes can be found using:

```
openssl dgst -md5 <filename>
```

-- I stopped here as this is where I found `debsums` which does all of what you want in one tidy package

sources: [Wikipedia on Deb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deb_(file_format)) and [Debsums ManPage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/man1/debsums.1.html)

Comment: `debsums` is amazing in one easy command! Should be at the top of your answer.